# Vtiger 7 workflow to create record in Quote Module

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I want to set a workflow in Vtiger 7 so that when the Quote stage is set to "Superceded" the quote is automatically duplicated and the newly created quote opened up ready for editing.

The simplest way to do this seems to be using the "Create Record" action in the Workflows. But for some reason the "Create Record" action seems to apply to every other module apart from Quotes.  The Quotes module simply does not exist in the dropdown list.

Can someone please advise how to code the so the "Create Record" dropdown list includes the Quotes module?  Alternatively how would I go about creating a custom function to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the Quote module record by writing Custom function. You have already id of your Quotes. You just need to pass the Quote id and perform the duplicate operation.

There are many references you will find on google to execute the custom function using workflow.

[Wiki](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Invoke_Custom_Function), [vTiger Discussion forum](https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/183672/invoke-custom-function/p1)